# diazo replaces <esi:include> tags with <include>

Tags: plone, diazo

I'm having problems with diazo for plone.

I have <esi:include> tags in my page templates but when I use diazo, all those tags are replaced by <include> even if I use mode="raw" or not.

I've found a ungly workaround:

```
<xsl:template css:match="include">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;esi:include src="</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@src" />
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">">&lt;/esi:include></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

But the <include> tags are not replaced by <esi:include when the html is put with mode="raw".

Any idea?

Thank you very much.

Comment: mode="raw" prevents the continued processing of content pulled in by other rules — in particular, content drop and replace rules. If mode="raw" fixes the problem, you should examine your rule set to see if it might be the villain here.

Comment: No in fact when I use standard rule (append before, so on), <esi:include> tags are always replaced by <include> even if I use mode="raw" or not.
I've found the workaround I mentionned in my post but it's not working when I want to move content with <drop> and <replace mode="raw">. In that case, my <esi:include> tag is again replaced.

Answer (score 2):

If you want bare XSL to be processed in raw mode, you'll need to add method="raw" to your xsl:template tag. You may need to have two versions of your template tag, one for method="raw" and one for default (no method attribute).

Templates in XSL only match if their method matches. If there's no method in the apply specified in the apply template tag, then the method is "default".

When you indicate 'mode="raw"' in Diazo, it puts method="raw" in the apply template call, which skips most post processing, including any XSL templates for which you don't specify method="raw".